# Finding Consecutive repetition of Elements in C# Array and Altering the element

Tags: c#, .net

I was given this problem

Given an int array length 3, if there is a 2 in the array immediately followed by a 3, 
set the 3 element to 0.
For Example ({1, 2, 3}) → {1, 2, 0}
            ({2, 3, 5}) → {2, 0, 5}
            ({1, 2, 1}) → {1, 2, 1}

And this is my implementation.

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 1 };
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                if (x[i] == 2 && x[i + 1] == 3)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (x[j]==3)
                        {
                            x[j] = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            foreach (int i in x)
            {
                Console.Write(i);
            }
```

I got zero as result. Can you help me to find where I am at mistake. I can't figure it out because the lecturer didn't gave any explanation in details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need all these loops: with the length of 3, you need to perform only two checks, like this:

```
if (x[0]==2 && x[1]==3) x[1] = 0;
if (x[1]==2 && x[2]==3) x[2] = 0;
```

For arrays of arbitrary size, you could use a single loop:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < x.Length-1 ; i++) {
    if (x[i]==2 && x[i+1]==3) x[i+1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: @JasmineAppelblad I would understand a single loop, but three nested loops for an array of three items is too much. One thing that is not correct about your three-loop program is `for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)`: it should be `for (int i = 0; i < x.Length-1; i++)`, otherwise you'd get an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have a proper check: `if (x[i] == 2 && x[i + 1] == 3)` However, there are 2 things you could improve on.

1) If you're going to do `x[i + 1]` you need to make sure that `i` can never be the last element of the array, because the `+ 1` will overflow the array. So instead of `i < x.Length` in the for loop, try `i < x.Length - 1`. It seems like duct taping, but there isn't really a better way (none I know of).

2) If the condition is true, you then have a `for` that will find and replace EVERY 3 in the array with a 0, regardless of if the 3 is preceded by a 2. You already know that `x[i]` is 2 and `x[i + 1]` is 3 (as determined by the `if` that we know at this point must be `true`), so the index of the 3 to be replaced is `i + 1`, thus: `x[i + 1] = 0;` No loop needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one loop.

```
 // In the test part of the for loop, use ' i < x.Length - 1'
 // so you don't evaluate the last element + 1 and get an IndexOutOfRangeException
 for (int i = 0; i < x.Length - 1; i++) 
 {
    if (x[i] == 2 && x[i + 1] == 3)
       x[i + 1] = 0;
 }
```